# Trying to install WebGraph to run a class

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to mvn and Java, I wanted to install http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22webgraph%22 and I've added it in Eclipse to my mvn project as dependency - ok that works. However I need to run a Class from this package, I've tried tu run (as it says on this site: http://law.di.unimi.it/tutorial.php - I'm trying to run WebGraph framework)

```
F:\mgr\from_maven>java -cp webgraph-3.3.1.jar it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.BVGraph -o -
O -L uk-2007-05@100000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/lang/Fly
weightPrototype
```

but as you can see it gives me error, I wanted to include dependency files so that there wouldn't be an error, problem is that there are a lot of dependency files so it could be difficult. As I suspect there have to be simpler way. On this site they would run it as

```
java it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.BVGraph -o -O -L basename
```

But then java can't find this class.

Could anyone show me how to do it? I would be grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea how they did it on their site but I've created simple bat script to run this class with all off it's dependencies:

```
@echo off
java -classpath collections-generic-4.01.jar;colt-1.2.0.jar;commons-collections-20040616.jar;commons-configuration-1.8.jar;commons-io-2.4.jar;commons-lang-2.6.jar;commons-math3-3.2.jar;concurrent-1.3.4.jar;dsiutils-2.1.8.jar;fastutil-6.5.12.jar;guava-16.0.1.jar;jsap-2.1.jar;jung-algorithms-2.0.1.jar;jung-api-2.0.1.jar;jung-io-2.0.1.jar;log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar;logback-classic-1.1.1.jar;logback-core-1.1.1.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar;stax-api-1.0.1.jar;sux4j-3.0.10.jar;webgraph-3.3.1.jar it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.BVGraph -o -O -L %1
```

Run using script.bat basename

Answer (score 0):

You may use dependency:copy-dependencies goal of maven. It will download all dependencies in to a folder under your target. Then adding your classpath prefix as that folder will solve the problem. To add the prefix to your manifest you can use smt like the following.

```
 <configuration>
    <archive>
       <manifest>
         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
         <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
       </manifest>
    </archive>
 </configuration>
```

It is setting it to lib here, but you can change it to the folder name which would be generated by dependency:copy-dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I have all dependencies in one folder because I've downloaded them before but I still don't know how to add this classpath prefix, could you explain it for me? Thanks

Comment: Well, add the path of that folder between the <classpathPrefix></classpathPrefix> tags in your pom file. I put the usage example above. I am assuming that this folder is under your target folder (in fact it may be anywhere). Then recompile your code. Then go and run your jar. Adding the above configuration to your pom will add that folder path to your manifest file. Detailed usage information can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

Comment: Ok but I don't have any code yet, I just wanted to build offsets by running it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.BVGraph as they said on tutorial on [this site](http://law.di.unimi.it/tutorial.php)

Answer (score 0):

First, use `maven dependency` to download all the necessary files in eclipse or IntelliJ(which I used).

Let us assume that webgraph-3.0.9.jar and all required dependencies are located in ./lib with respect to current directory.

Then you could use `java it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.BVGraph -o -O -L basename` to do your job.